# How to match regex till first space

Tags: python, regex

`is there any way to do [^\s] negate from the first space`

I have a below file

```
server1 192.168.1.1  xx.xxx.xxx
server1 192.168.1.2  xx.sc.sss
server1 192.168.1.3  drf.xs.ffd
server2 192.168.1.1  .ssvfd
server2 192.168.1.2  sddfwe.ss
server2 192.168.1.3  kkl.ssdd.dd
```

My Code

```
import re
file_= (r'C:\Users\mous\Desktop\test.txt')
[line for line in open(file_,'r',encoding='utf-8') if re.findall(r'server1 (\w+)',line)]
```

My out(not proper)

```
['server1 192.168.1.1  xx.xxx.xxx\n',
 'server1 192.168.1.2  xx.sc.sss\n',
 'server1 192.168.1.3  drf.xs.ffd\n']
```

My First expected out

`['server1 192.168.1.1',
 'server1 192.168.1.2',
 'server1 192.168.1.3']`

My Second expected Out

`['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.2','192.168.1.3']`

Comment: `re.findall(r'(server1 (\S+))', open(file_,'r',encoding='utf-8').read())`

Comment: Make use of anchors and lazy quantifiers [`^.+? .+?(?= )`](https://regex101.com/r/20glfT/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice how you take `[line for line in ...]`. the elements in the result of this comprehension will be the complete lines.

you use the regex just for the filtering.

lucky for you, `re.findall` can take the entire file and return just the results you want without ever splitting to lines, just use:

```py
re.findall(r'(server1 (\w+))', open(file_,'r',encoding='utf-8').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `re` ?

```
# from io  import StringIO

# s = '''server1 192.168.1.1  xx.xxx.xxx
# server1 192.168.1.2  xx.sc.sss
# server1 192.168.1.3  drf.xs.ffd
# server2 192.168.1.1  .ssvfd
# server2 192.168.1.2  sddfwe.ss
# server2 192.168.1.3  kkl.ssdd.dd'''

with StringIO(s) as f:
    for line in f:
        prts = line.split()
        if prts[0].endswith('1'):
            print(prts[1])

# 192.168.1.1
# 192.168.1.2
# 192.168.1.3
```

or

```
...
    ...
        print(' '.join(prts[:2]))

# server1 192.168.1.1
# server1 192.168.1.2
# server1 192.168.1.3
```